# Mongoose query that finds all items of type B with entries in B.array that have a match in A.array

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a model `Person`

```
schemas.person = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstname: {type: String},
    lastname: {type: String},
    age: Number,
    email: {type: String},
    gender: {type: String},
    matches: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: models.Person}],
});
```

`matches` are references to another person who has similar interests (i.e. for dating purposes)

Suppose I have 10 `male`s and 10 `female`s.

I want to write a query that gives me a male who is a mutual match to all 10 females - that is, all 10 females appear in his `matches` array and he appears in the `matches` arrays of all 10 females.

So in pseudocode, it would look something like this:

```
models.Person.find({"gender": "male"}).exec(function(err, men){
     models.Person.find({"gender": "female"}).exec(function(err, women){
          models.Person.find(some item from men.matches $in all women.matches}, function(err, result){
               console.log(result);
          } 
     }
});
```

That last part **`some item from men.matches $in all women.matches`** what I don't know how to say in Mongoose, and I can't find a good way to, online.

Take note, that the matches array looks like:

```
     [
        {
            "$oid": "558ced061d35bd072e7b5825"
        },
        {
            "$oid": "558ced061d35bd072e7b58a0"
        },
        {
            "$oid": "558ced061d35bd072e7b58c6"
        }
    ]
```

Is there some way to express this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two key criteria is that for every person to have a match:

1. The `id` of the possible match has to be in their `matches` array
2. Their `id` has to be in the `matches` array of another person

The third mentioned criteria that a match be a female should already be accounted for by inclusion in the `matches` array assuming this preference restriction is mirrored there. If not, why limit their matches here and not there? That said, it would be a simple additional query param to add and I'll leave that up to you. [*#LoveWins*](https://twitter.com/search?q=%23LoveWins)

So, here is one approach using a find to get a list of all men and then using a second find to retrieve all possible matches (without gender exclusion).

```
models.Person.find({
  gender: "male"
}).exec().then(function gotAllMen(persons) {
  // persons is an array of men

  // Find any matches for each person
  return new Promise.all(persons.map(function(person) {
    return models.Person.find({
      _id: {$in: person.matches}, // Satisfies 1
      matches: person._id // Satisfies 2
    }).exec().then(function(match) {
      // Create a new object for each match
      return {
        person: person,
        match: match
      };
    });
  }));
}).then(function matches(matches) {
  // Have a date
});
```

*Note: this is untested code*

Comment: plus 1 for the _// Have a date_ signature :-) Nice match algorithm!

Comment: @chridam thanks! :-) Although I am not sure I would use it in production without at least using a stream on the initial find.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use in production?

Comment: @Imray I updated to show more explicitly that the first `find` returns an array of all matching persons (men in this instance). This could be a large array depending on your collection size. If it is I might explore using streams or including more criteria (maybe checking if a person has at least one match).

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to first get an array of all the female id's, compare this array with that of the male query's `matches` field and finally iterate over the females query to find a match.

To aid in explaining the above concept, suppose you create a test collection in mongo shell with the following documents (shortened schema for brevity and clarity):

```
db.test.insert([
    {
        "_id" : 1,
        "gender" : "female",
        "name" : "a",
        "matches" : [6, 10]
    },{
        "_id" : 2,
        "gender" : "female",
        "name" : "b",
        "matches" : [7, 10]
    },{
        "_id" : 3,
        "gender" : "female",
        "name" : "c",
        "matches" : [8, 10]
    },{
        "_id" : 4,
        "gender" : "female",
        "name" : "d",
        "matches" : [9, 10]
    },{
        "_id" : 5,
        "gender" : "female",
        "name" : "e",
        "matches" : [10]
    },{
        "_id" : 6,
        "gender" : "male",
        "name" : "f",
        "matches" : [1, 3 ]
    },{
        "_id" : 7,
        "gender" : "male",
        "name" : "g",
        "matches" : [1, 2 ]
    },{
        "_id" : 8,
        "gender" : "male",
        "name" : "h",
        "matches" : [3, 5]
    },{
        "_id" : 9,
        "gender" : "male",
        "name" : "i",
        "matches" : [5]
    },{
        "_id" : 10,
        "gender" : "male",
        "name" : "j",
        "matches" : [1,2,3,4,5]
    }
])
```

From observation, it can be seen that person with _id: 10 satisfies the query that gives you a male who is a mutual match to all 5 females - that is, all 5 females appear in his matches array and he appears in the matches arrays of all 5 females.

Now how do we translate this query in mongo shell?

```
function arraysEqual(a, b) {
    if (a === b) return true;
    if (a == null || b == null) return false;
    if (a.length != b.length) return false;

    a.sort();
    b.sort();
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
        if (a[i] !== b[i]) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

var all_females = db.test.find({"gender": "female"}).map(function(p){return p._id}),
    male = {}, 
    matched = {};

db.test.find({"gender": "male"}).forEach(function (m){
    if (arraysEqual(m.matches, all_females)) male = m;
});

var matches = db.test.find({"gender": "female", "matches": male._id}).map(function(p){return p._id});
if (arraysEqual(matches, all_females)) matched = male;
printjson(matched);
```

**Output**:

```
{
    "_id" : 10,
    "gender" : "male",
    "name" : "j",
    "matches" : [1,2,3,4,5]
}
```

Now you can implement the above in Mongoose using helper methods **[`_.each()`](https://lodash.com/docs#forEach)** and **[`_.isEqual()`](https://lodash.com/docs#isEqual)** from **[lodash](https://lodash.com/)** library as follows (untested):

```
var male = {}, 
    matched = {};
models.Person.find({"gender": "female"}).exec(function(err, docs){
    if(err) return res.send(err);
    var all_females = docs.map(function(p){return p._id});
    models.Person.find({"gender": "male"}).exec(function(err, men){
        _.each(men, function(m, i) {
            if (_.isEqual(all_females, m.matched)) male = m;
        });
        models.Person.find({"gender": "female", "matches": male._id}).exec(function(err, women){
            var matched_females = women.map(function(w){return w._id});
            if (_.isEqual(all_females, matched_females)) matched = male;
            console.log(matched);
        });     
    });
});
```